# How to generate Java array from C pointer in SWIG

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

Given is this C code:

```
typedef struct _B {
 /* something */
} B;

typedef struct _A {
    int numBs; /* The count of Bs in the array bellow */
    B *b;
} A;
```

I would like to access A.b as an array in Java

```
A a = new A();
B[] b = a.getB();
```

Do you have an Idea how to do this with SWIG? I played around with carrays.i, without success. Consider that `B *b` does not always have to be an array, only in this particular structure.

Comment: Create an NIO direct byte buffer using the original address, and then use the NIO Buffer methods to access the memory as an array.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you give an example how to achive this (the SWIG interface file)? The best result i can get is `B b = a.getB()` instead of `B[] b = a.getB()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with SWIG. The tricky part is that as you spotted SWIG is inclined to assume that `B*` is a pointer to an `Object`, not the start of some array.

Since the array contains many non-primitive instances each instance is going to require the creation of a Java object that is a proxy for the corresponding `B` instance in your C array. There are two places you could cause those to be generated. Either you could write some C that creates each `Object` and sticks it in a `jobjectArray`, or you could write some Java that takes advantage of the fact that SWIG can trivially be made to generate a specific proxy for any specific member. I think the latter solution is simpler and cleaner so I've made an example using that approach:

```
%module test

%ignore A_::b; // We will wrap this another way
%typemap(javacode) A %{
  public B[] getB() {
    B[] ret = new B[getNumBs()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; ++i) {
      ret[i] = getB(i);
    }
    return ret;
  }
%}

// Or %include etc.
%inline %{
typedef struct B_ {
 /* something */
} B;

typedef struct A_ {
    int numBs; /* The count of Bs in the array bellow */
    B *b;
} A;
%}

%javamethodmodifiers A_::getB(size_t pos) "private";
%extend A_ {
  // This defaults to non-owning, which is exactly what we want
  B *getB(size_t pos) {
    assert(pos < $self->numBs); // TODO: real error handling
    return $self->b+pos;
  }
}
```

The `%extend` provides one extra method in Java that gets any `B` in your C array of `B`s. Since this is an implementation detail I made it private.

We also told SWIG not to wrap the `B *b` pointer - we're going to supply our own wrapping for that manually instead. This is provided via the `javacode` typemap. Inside that typemap we build up our Java array by calling our helper once per item in the array.

With that in place it's now sufficient for you to do:

```java
A a = new A();
B[] b = a.getB();
```

Crucially because we only ignored the specific member of `A` it won't interfere with other uses of `B *b`.